# Invalid connection error ('08001')for importing CSV to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am looking for a solution for inserting CSV file to SQL Server and for inserting data to SQL Server I faced with below error.
I read lot about this issue and did several changes but nothing happened and still I can't import csv to relative table. I can't understand why this error also happened?

Microsoft SQL has been installed on my local computer:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver=SQL Server; Server=ServerName\MSSQLSERVER; Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=yes ; UID=Administrator')
```

Error:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]Invalid connection. (14) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver][DBMSLPCN]ConnectionOpen (ParseConnectParams()). (14)')

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL if you are using SQL Server?

Comment: I'm not sure if that matters, but connection string should be `'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=....` (missing `{}`).

Comment: I add {} , but the same error I got .

Comment: Choose one authentication scheme. For Windows authentication use `Trusted_Connection=yes` without UID or PWD. For SQL Login authentication use `UID=YourUsername;PWD=YourPassword` without Trusted_Connection.

Comment: I am now connecting with SQL Authentication, I removed Trusted_Connection ='yes' and add user name and password instea but the same error i faced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who faced with above problem,If you want to connect to sql server with SQL Authentication, the format will be changed as below:

> pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server}; Server=ServerName;
> Database=DBName; UID=UserName; PWD= {Password};')